# SQLfiddle Errno: 150 - Foreign Key Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

When I try to set a Foreign key, it throws the Error number 150.

**Schema Creation Failed: Can't create table 'db_2_f856e.urlnames'**

This is the code:

```
create table images(
     id int auto_increment primary key
    ,gender varchar(6)
    ,pattern varchar(50)
    ,item_name varchar(25)
    ,url_id int(250)
)//

create table urlnames(
     url_id_no int(250)
    ,url varchar(250)
    ,foreign key (url_id_no) references images(url_id)
)//
```

Can someone explain why it is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure doesn't make sense.  I think you want:

```
create table urlnames(
     url_id_no int auto_increment primary key,
     url varchar(250)
);

create table images(
     image_id int auto_increment primary key,
     gender varchar(6),
     pattern varchar(50),
     item_name varchar(25),
     url_id int(250) references urlnames(url_id_no)
);
```

Any column referenced by a foreign key reference needs to be a primary key or unique key.  And, `urlnames` should have its `id` column declared as a primary key.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd3fb5) is a SQL Fiddle example.